# How to find out what's wrong on all of my Qt programs?

Tags: arch-linux, qt4, qtcreator

I'm using Arch Linux (Linux 3.13), when I run `qtcreator`, it crashes, and the same happens for other Qt based software:

```
$ qtcreator
"Qt Warning - invalid keysym: dead_actute" 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ qtalarm 
"Qt Warning - invalid keysym: dead_actute"  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

all my "qt" installed packages are:

```
gambas3-gb-qt4 3.5.2-1
gambas3-gb-qt4-ext 3.5.2-1
gambas3-gb-qt4-opengl 3.5.2-1
gambas3-gb-qt4-webkit 3.5.2-1
kdebindings-qtruby 4.12.1-1
kdebindings-smokeqt 4.12.1-1
libdbusmenu-qt 0.9.2-2
phonon-qt4 4.7.1-1
polkit-qt 0.103.0-2
poppler-qt4 0.24.5-1
pyqt4-common 4.10.3-1
python2-pyqt4 4.10.3-1
qt4 4.8.5-7
qt5-base 5.2.0-3
qt5-declarative 5.2.0-3
qt5-graphicaleffects 5.2.0-3
qt5-imageformats 5.2.0-3
qt5-jsbackend 5.1.1-5
qt5-location 5.2.0-3
qt5-multimedia 5.2.0-3
qt5-qtsystems-git 20130509-1
qt5-quick1 5.2.0-3
qt5-quickcontrols 5.2.0-3
qt5-script 5.2.0-3
qt5-sensors 5.2.0-3
qt5-serialport 5.2.0-3
qt5-svg 5.2.0-3
qt5-tools 5.2.0-3
qt5-translations 5.2.0-3
qt5-webkit 5.2.0-3
qt5-x11extras 5.2.0-3
qt5-xmlpatterns 5.2.0-3
qtalarm 4700237.6-1
qtchooser 39-1
qtcreator 3.0.0-2
qtwebkit 2.3.3-1
telepathy-qt 0.9.3-7
```

How can I find out what's wrong (what the cause of the problem is) on my system?

Comment: To find out what's wrong with the warning and how to fix it see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling qt packages solves the problem..

Answer (score 6):

The typo inside libX11 has been fixed upstream with commit 5dcb40f28d59587597d2ff6e6ac64c71cfe6ff7b and date 2013-09-17, and if you look at the [commit log](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/log/) you'll see that this commit is above the last commit which got into release 1.6.2 of libX11. (2013-09-13)

The 1.6.2 release is currently used in the extra repository on ArchLinux: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/libx11#n5

Which means that **the fix upstream hasn't got into the Arch repos yet**, we'll have to wait for the next release of libX11 which hasn't happened as of current date.

Until the next release of libX11 you can fix this yourself by doing:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/dead_actute/dead_acute/' /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
```

After that, the message "Qt Warning - invalid keysym: dead_actute" displayed when starting a Qt based application will be gone.

As for the SIGSEGV problem, try to run Qt Creator, or the other Qt based apps your trying to run through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or the tools mentioned [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Profiling-and-Memory-Checking-Tools) and check the output.

Answer (score 2):

`dead_actute` is a typo and should be `dead_acute`.

- [Bug 69476 - UTF-8 locale typo, 'dead_actute' should 'dead_acute'](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69476)

Always make sure to take any errors that get produced by tools and search on them. Most of the time if one person is encountering an error there are bound to be more.

Comment: that's just warning, the error was "Segmentation Fault"

Comment: Have you tried to fix the `dead_actute` bug? Maybe it's the cause of the segmentation fault

Comment: @danielkullmann The warning cannot be the cause of the segfault